# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pointers, warnings

I have yet another pesky warning I would like gone. Basically, I have an int declared like this: `@property (nonatomic, assign) int *myInt;` and set like this: `myInt = 0;`. It is also synthesized in the implementation file. I am getting a warning on the line where I set the int's value and it says `Incompatible intiger to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int'.` What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There's a big hint in the error message!

In C and Objective C, an `int` is a primitive data type. You've written `int *`, which means "a pointer to an int", whereas it looks like you just wanted an int.

So change your property to this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int myInt;
```

For more info, google "C pointers" and you'll find information like this: http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm

Answer (score 15):

Yes, simply remove asterisk (`*`) from declaration.

for example.declare **BOOL isChecked** instead of **BOOL * isChecked**.

Answer (score 3):

`int *MyInt` is a pointer to int, not an int.
As others told you, just remove the `*` and you will have a regular int.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to resolve this is to simply not declare a pointer (drop the asterisk):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSUInteger myObjcInt;  // unsigned ( >= 0 ) NSObject int, yo
}
```

Comment: That's not another way — it's the same thing occulus said. BTW, your comment calls it an "NSObject int", which doesn't really make a lot of sense as a term.

Comment: Touche. I was reading this post during a search for an NSInteger-related issue, not Int.  A little too quick on the reply there, guys.  My bad.