# assign value from server to integer in objective -c

Tags: objective-c, int, nsuinteger

I am coming from swift background, I have a code in objective -c that take value from server and it takes correctly here is the code bellow.

```
if (![message_expiration intValue]){
    NSLog(@"Check the message expiration integer value");


    _MessageExpire = [message_expiration intValue];




}
```

and I have a variable:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger *MessageExpire;
```

what I want is:  My variable that is integer takes the value that come from server  and I did in this way :

```
_MessageExpire = [message_expiration intValue];
```

but I get the error that say: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning .....

Any help appreciate

Comment: Remove `*` after `NSInteger`. It's not a pointer.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293406/another-warning-question-incompatible-integer-to-pointer-conversion-assigning

Comment: BTW: Please respect the Objective-C naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan, it works and thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Objective - C

Did not assign pointer(*) to `NSInteger`

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger MessageExpire;
```