# Vigénere Cipher in C

Tags: c, encryption, cs50, vigenere

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // strlen()
#include <ctype.h> // isupper() , tolower()

void vigenereCipher(char* plainText, char* key);

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    char* key = argv[1];
    char plainText[101];

    // Ask the user for a sentence/word to encrypt
    printf("Please enter a word or sentence: ");
    fgets(plainText, sizeof(plainText), stdin);

    // Print the used encryption key
    printf("Your encryption key: %s\n", key);

    // Print the encrypted plaintext
    printf("Your encrypted message is: ");
    vigenereCipher(plainText, key);

    return 0;
}
void vigenereCipher(char* plainText, char* key)
{

    int i;
    char cipher;
    char cipherValue;
    int len = strlen(key);

    // Loop through the length of the plainText string
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(plainText); i++)
    {

        if (islower(plainText[i]))
        {
            cipherValue = ((int)plainText[i] - 97 + (int)tolower(key[i % len]) - 97) % 26 + 97;
            cipher = (char)cipherValue;
        }
        else
        {
            cipherValue = ((int)plainText[i] - 65 + (int)toupper(key[i % len]) - 65) % 26 + 65;
            cipher = (char)cipherValue;
        }

        // Print the ciphered character if it is alpha numeric
        if (isalpha(plainText[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", cipher);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", plainText[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

> vigenere.c:7:5: error: second parameter of 'main' (argument array)
>   must be of type 'char **' int main(int argc, char argv[])
>       ^ vigenere.c:10:15: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'char';
>   take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
>           char* key = argv[1];
>                 ^     ~~~~~~~
>                       & 2 errors generated.

I'm aiming for the `encryption` key of the program to be provided as an argument to the program but got the 2 errors above and don't know where to go from here. Any ideas? (end of code snippet)

This is for the `CS50` project.

Comment: it's ` int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: Isn't the error self explanatory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int \*' from 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293406/incompatible-integer-to-pointer-conversion-assigning-to-int-from-int)

Comment: @LioraHaydont Forget about the duplicate. This question should be closed under: simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard signature for `main()` is either an array of character pointers:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Or if you prefer a pointer to other pointer(s) to characters:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

What you have is an array of characters.

Comment: That was it, thank you @tadman, I went with the pointer to other pointer(s) to characters approach and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You have missed an asterisk `*` in `main`. The second parameter of `main` is an array of `char` pointers: `char *argv[]`.

Please note, as arrays decay to pointers when passing it to a function, it is also valid to write the second parameter as:

`char **argv`.

So, your `main()` should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
}
```